# find shortest path in a maze | asked in google interview

Tags: python

question:  Write a function answer(map) that generates the length of the shortest path from the prison door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans.

The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable (0).

The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

**Inputs:**

```
(int) maze = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

**Output:**

```
(int) 7
```

**Inputs:**

```
(int) maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

**Output:**

```
(int) 11
```

---

I wrote a program, and its working on local, but somehow it's not working when I submit and verify it to online,

***it only passes the first test out of 5***

I know first two tests input, I tested em individually and it's working on local

```
import sys
counter = 1
lol = []
def lolit(k):
    global lol
    lol.append(k)

def isSafe(mat, visited, i, j):
    try:
        if(mat[i][j] == 1 or visited[i][j]):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    except:
        return False

def isValid(i,j,M):
    if (i < M and j < M and i >= 0 and j >= 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def findShortestPath(mat,visited,i,j,k):
    global counter
    M = len(visited)
    if(i == M-1 and j == M-1):

        lolit(k)        
        counter = k


    else:          
        visited[i][j] = 1 


        '''go to bottom'''
        if(isValid(i + 1, j,M) and isSafe(mat, visited, i + 1, j)):

            findShortestPath(mat, visited, i + 1, j,k+1)


        if (isValid(i, j + 1,M) and isSafe(mat, visited, i, j + 1)):

            findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j + 1,k+1)



        if (isValid(i - 1, j,M) and isSafe(mat, visited, i - 1, j)):

            findShortestPath(mat, visited, i - 1, j,k+1)


        if (isValid(i, j - 1,M) and isSafe(mat, visited, i, j - 1)):

            findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j - 1,k+1)

    return counter




def answer(mat):
    global lol
    L = len(mat)
    visited = [[0 for x in range(L)] for y in range(L)]

    nr = []
    findShortestPath(mat,visited,0,0,1)

    for indexi,nakul in enumerate(mat):
        for indexj,rathore in enumerate(nakul):
            if(rathore == 1):
                nr.append([indexi,indexj])
    for indexm,nrm in enumerate(nr):
        mat[nrm[0]][nrm[1]] = 0
        visited = [[0 for x in range(L)] for y in range(L)]
        findShortestPath(mat,visited,0,0,1)
        mat[nrm[0]][nrm[1]] = 1
    ping = min(lol)
    lol =[]
    return ping

print answer([[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]])   

print answer([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What is the URL you're submitting to?

Comment: its foobar panel of google